# @AuthenticationPrincipal doesn't show the authenticated user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have the following code, which uses the @AuthenticationPrincipal to find the authenticated user

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/update",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody User editUser(@RequestBody User newUser, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("Authenticated User="+user);
}
```

The problem is, when I print out the user's name, it shows up as an empty user, not the one who was logged in. What do I need to do differently to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching around, I found [this form page](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/739234-authenticationprincipal-doesn-t-return-the-authenticated-user). It directed me to add `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` to my Application. After adding that, it works great!